# How can I change my code so that it reads words with punctuation differently?

Tags: unix, word-count

This code works perfectly and  it differs between lower case and upper case words like How and how are two different things, but if I wanna say how and how, they are the same. How can I fix the code to differentiate between them ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE* f = fopen (argv[1], "r");
char buffer[10000];
if (argc != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);

}
fclose(f);
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "tr -cs '[a-z][A-Z]' '[\\n*]' < %s |"
                                 " sort | uniq -c | sort -n", argv[1]);
return(system(buffer));
}
```

Comment: Since this is basically a question on how to use some unix commands Super User would be more appropriate, as it really isn't a programming question.

Comment: `man tr` for the man page on how to use `tr`. This isn't a question about C.

Comment: What is Super User? Sorry I am a newbie here